# Chinese IME - Change the font used in the suggestions list

Tags: snow-leopard, text-input

Is there a way to change what font is used to display the 'suggestions' list in OS-X 10.6+ when using the Chinese IME (simplified)?  I've looked around in the preferences (particulary 'Candidate Window'), but found nothing.

The font used is not the standard new and pretty one, but the old blocky one with slightly ugly/odd looking characters.

I assume this will take some plist editing, but have no clue which one to look at.

`~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.inputmethod.SCMI.plist` doesn't have it
  `~/Librara/Preferences/Input Methods` is empty

**Update:**

For the moment I have switched to [QIM Input](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/21836/imkqim), and it is working pretty well. Linked to that page because the main site is not in english.  The app is very well translated though.

- Pros

  - Many more options (most of which I don't understand)
  - Can change font face / color / size /background
  - Skinnable (sogu skins, ugly though)
- Cons:

  - Puts characters and number selector together in same color, making it a little difficult to tell what is 'candidate #1, #2, etc'.  Maybe a skin can fix this.

Comment: I tried searching for potential preference keys with `strings /System/Library/Input\ Methods/SCIM.app/Contents/MacOS/SCIM  | grep -E '^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]{10,80}$' | sort | uniq | pbcopy`, but didn't find anything promising.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on how to search like that, didn't know.  I'm guessing it just uses a hard-coded system font.  Sigh.

Comment: @AndrewBacker Being a native Chinese, I found Apple making the best input method. The predictive text is better than ever, and they have a large enough word database so I don't have to correct much.

Comment: I'll check out apples, maybe it has improved since 10.5.  QIM has been great, and predictions have been spot on.